# resizeIframe onLoad of Iframe and onClick event from another Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize

I have two Iframe on my page. One is called navigation and other is called content. On loading of Iframes I call the following function:

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
  if (obj.contentWindow != undefined && obj.contentWindow != null && obj.contentWindow.document != undefined && obj.contentWindow.document != null) {
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 20 + 'px';
  obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
  }
}
```

And I call the above function on Iframe like this

```
   <iframe src="Taxonomy.htm" name="navigation" id="navigation" width="250" height="900" seamless="true" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>         
   <div id="divContent"><script>
   document.write('<iframe src="' + newPath + '" id="content" name="content" width="700"   height="900" seamless="true" onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this)">');
   document.write('</iframe>');  
   </script></div>
```

And I call another function called `doContentLoad()` when a link in navigation `Iframe` is clicked and the function do like this:

```
function doContentLoad() {
      var navFrameElem = indow.parent.document.getElementById("navigation").contentWindow  || window.parent.document.getElementById("navigation").contentDocument;
      if (navFrameElem != null && navFrameElem.document) 
           navFrameElem = navFrameElem.document;
      if (navFrameElem != null) {
        if (navFrameElem.body.scrollHeight > 900) {                window.parent.document.getElementById("navigation").parentNode.parentNode.style.height = navFrameElem.body.scrollHeight + 130 + 'px';
          window.parent.document.getElementById("navigation").style.height = navFrameElem.body.scrollHeight + 130 + 'px';
          navFrameElem.body.style.height = navFrameElem.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    }

    var contentFrameElem = window.parent.document.getElementById("content").contentWindow || window.parent.document.getElementById("content").contentDocument;
    if (contentFrameElem != null && contentFrameElem.document != null &&  contentFrameElem.document) contentFrameElem = contentFrameElem.document;               window.parent.document.getElementById("content").style.height = contentFrameElem.body.scrollHeight + 30 + 'px';   
     }
```

I get the following error in `Firefox : Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'` in both functions.

In `IE I get:  invalid calling object.`

How can I get document object here? or is there better to resize `Iframes`?

Comment: Not related to the question, but I'd suggest you to cache some references. Now you're repeating certain long references over and over again. That makes your code very hard to read.

Comment: I have this problem only when I am trying to get height of Iframe when the PDF document is inside. So the PDF document says Permission denied for getting document property of Iframe?? Any one has idea about this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your including a PDF, rather than an HTML page, the iframe contentWindow has no DOM, so JavaScript can not access any properties in the iFrame.